# Sort from low to high the two dimensional int arrays according to the sum of arr[i]

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've got to a dead end in the homework working on sorting a integers two-dimensional array.

The instructions are to create a function that takes a two-dimensional int array
(not necessarily a matrix) and sort the Outer array according to the sum of the inner arrays. in other words, in the first index of the array should be the inner array with the lowest sum.

Example - 
input - int[][] array = {{2, 4, 1,9,9,9,9}, {6, 8}, {7, 3, 6, 5, 1}};

output - array = {{6, 8}, {7, 3, 6, 5, 1}, {2, 4, 1,9,9,9,9}};

My logic so far is creating a new one dimensional array that will include the sum
of each of the inner arrays from the main array.
and work with the sorting according to it.

```
public static int[] arraysCalculator(int[][] arr) { 
int[] sums = new int[arr.length];
int sum= 0;
for(int i = 0; i  < arr.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
    {
        sum += arr[i][j];
    }
    sums[i] = sum;
    sum = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily sum an `int[]` by streaming it and then calling `sum()`. From there, it's just a matter of calling `Arrays.sort` with a comparator that compares this sum:

```
Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> Arrays.stream(a).sum()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You got like one third. What you need now:

- after creating that first array `sums` that contains the **sums** of the "inner" arrays, you simply create an exact **copy** of that array, like `originalSums`
- then, you **sort** the content of `sums`

Example: say `sums` and `originalSums` are `[ 12, 3, 7]`. After sorting you get:

`originalSums`: `[ 12, 3, 7]`

`sums`: `[ 3, 7, 12]`

The thing is: by looking at both arrays, you can decide how to swap the inner arrays to match the order that `sums` shows you now.

In the above example, you notice that `12` has the original index 0. After sorting, its index is 2. So you know that you have to "swap" the inner arrays for 0 and 2. You can also deduce that `3` should go to index 0, and `7` to index 2.

Of course, it is still a bit of work to ensure that the swapping works out (like you better not swap any index *twice*).

The most basic way to get the whole thing going is to simply look at just one index at a time (like you do some sort of bubble sort).

Long story short: there are many different ways to solve this. I suggest you start with the easiest path.

Comment: i do not ask for code, i do appreciate if people are correcting my misunderstanding.

Comment: Also, Once i have a int[] array that each index in it includes the sum of the matching inner array from the bigger one.  from that point i can use bubble sort to sort the bigger array According to my small array. But for some reason my code does not work, i belive i got the logic right though.

Comment: @AvivDavidMalka See my answer. I did my best to provide you with both code and explanations on *what* each part does and *why* it does that. So even though you didn't ask for any code, sometimes learning from working examples is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers who did a great job explaining the theory and laying the ground work for solving your assignment, here is a full working example *(with detailed documentation on what each thing does and why)* that will hopefully be of some assistance:

```
/**
 * This method will sort the inner arrays of a given two dimensional array
 * from lowest to highest value according to the sum of it's elements.
 */
private static int[][] arrayCalc(int[][] arr)
{
    /*
     * We're working with a TreeMap here because this type
     * of map is allowed to have duplicate key entries
     */
    java.util.Map<Integer, Integer[]> map = new java.util.TreeMap<>();
    /*
     * This value represents the largest inner array
     * size found in 2d array passed as parameter
     */
    int largestSize = 0;
    for (int[] inner : arr) {
        /*
         * Convert the inner array to an array of Integer
         * objects so it can be placed inside a map
         */
        Integer[] integers = IntStream.of(inner).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
        map.put(IntStream.of(inner).sum(), integers);
        /*
         * Check if this inner array has a larger value
         * then the largest array we processed so far
         */
        if (inner.length > largestSize) {
            largestSize = inner.length;
        }
    }

    int[][] result = new int[map.size()][largestSize];
    /*
     * Iterate over the map and copy it's values which are represented
     * as Integer arrays into inner arrays of our return value
     */
    java.util.Iterator<java.util.Map.Entry<Integer, Integer[]>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length && iter.hasNext(); i++)
    {
        java.util.Map.Entry<Integer, Integer[]> entry = iter.next();
        /*
         * We can just return our value as an array of Integer objects
         * but for the sake of this exercise we will convert it to a
         * primitive 2D int array so it's consistent with our method parameter
         */
        Integer[] integers = entry.getValue();
        result[i] = java.util.Arrays.stream(integers).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] array = {{2, 4, 1,9,9,9,9}, {6, 8}, {7, 3, 6, 5, 1}};
    int[][] result = arrayCalc(array);

    for (int[] iResult : result) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(iResult));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[6, 8]
[7, 3, 6, 5, 1]
[2, 4, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```